# How to get indices of IntStream.map.forEach?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have this line which prints the squares of the numbers 0 to 5:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 4).map(i ->i*i).forEach(System.out::println);
```

The output is

```
0
1
4
9
16
```

Is there a way to get the output like below?

```
0 :0
1 :1
2 :4
3 :9
4 :16
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you `map` `i` to `i*i` you lose the original `i`.

You can remove the `map` and do the calculation inside the `forEach`:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 4).forEach(i -> System.out.println(i + ": " + i*i));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the short and clear explanation and of course for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Or you could do it like this(mapping to a `Pair` of key/value):

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 4)
         .mapToObj(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(i, i * i))
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Very nice alternative. This is may be the right solution if the calculation is not such simple like i*i. Thank you very much.